# ExceptionHandler not working my resume project

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, exception

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@RestControllerAdvice(basePackages = "com.cvresumeproject.cvresumeproject.service.*")
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {CustomNotFoundException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleEntityNotFound(CustomNotFoundException exception){
        ApiError apiError =new ApiError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        apiError.setMessage(exception.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError,apiError.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Main class

```
  @SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.cvresumeproject.cvresumeproject.ExceptionHandler.RestExceptionHandler")
public class CvresumeprojectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CvresumeprojectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Using my customnotfoundexception

```
 @Override
    public TemplateDto findById(Long id) throws CustomNotFoundException {
        return templateMapper.templateToTemplateDto(templateRepository.findById(id).get());
    }
```

**My resume project using exceptionhandler but this exception handler not working please help me Thanks!!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `*` in the `basePackages` element in `@RestControllerAdvice`. Controllers that belong to the configured base packages or sub-packages thereof will be included, so you don't need the wildcard. Use the following instead:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice(basePackages = "com.cvresumeproject.cvresumeproject.service")
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {CustomNotFoundException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleEntityNotFound(Exception exception, WebRequest webRequest) {
        HttpStatus errorCode = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(errorCode);
        apiError.setMessage(exception.getMessage());

        return this.handleExceptionInternal(exception, apiError, new HttpHeaders(), errorCode, webRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Back INTERNAL SERVER ERROR status 500

Comment: Then there is an issue with your Exception handler. Can you add `ApiError` to your answer?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try this.

Comment: I will need more details so that I can help you further. Do you get any exception? If not do you get the wrong HTTP status? While debugging do you see the exception handler being invoked?